# Inconsistent error when running a Test - UFT\QTP

Tags: qtp, hp-uft

I'm having an issue (sometimes), when running my tests through QC(ALM) on QTP\UFT.
It's a bit frustrating since it happens sometimes and I can't point the reason.

```html
On Error Resume Next
    
         
        Set mCnXLS = CreateObject("ADODB.connection")
        
        With mCnXLS
           
           
           .ConnectionString = "Driver={Microsoft Excel Driver (*.xls, *.xlsx, *.xlsm, *.xlsb)};" & _
           "DBQ=" & sXlsPath &";"&"HDR=Yes;ReadOnly=0;"

              
            .Open
        End With
        
        If Err.Number <> 0 Then
            
            MsgBox "fXLSConnect " & Err.Number & " - " & Err.Description, vbCritical, "clsDB"
            reporter.ReportEvent micPass ,"dd",Err.Description &" "&Err.Number
            Set mCnXLS = Nothing
            Err.Clear
            
            fXLSConnect = FALSE
            Exit Function
        End If
```

When debugging, it fails on the connection string to excel.

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: hi @vins 
the error is: fXLSConnect -2147024882 - [Microsoft][ODBC Excel]